# How to make a facebook type stream in UITableview

Tags: iphone, facebook

[image]

Facebook stream displays everything in a tableview format , i am confused how they implemented this:

Display single images, multiple images , videos, rendered data from other websites neatly on iPhone and somewhat similar to what we see on web.

Can somebody please help with the logic to implement such UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take help of custom cell in uitableview and implement the same scenario. In the custom cell, you can put images,unbutton and what so ever. Also you need to put toolbar and buttons as per your likings where the notification and all other buttons are put.

Comment: its not string which is clickable,its a custom button and also you can reload the table to refresh the data and multiple images can be inserted using custom cell. Plenty of tutorials are available on the same.

Comment: I am curious to know that are facebook dev rendering HTML for showing the above view and timeline view in the latest iPhone/iPad app?

Comment: i feel they are rendering XHTML in there webservices to display the UI, please correct my understanding?

Comment: if you are focusing on Facebook only then it is a UIWebview in which the the Facebook page is loaded.

Comment: Thanks for that information, i guessed the same.
I am confused about some points:
1. Is it UIWebView in every UITableview cell or there is just one complete UIWeBView which makes the Tableview through html.
2. How will i calculate the height of the html Content in a UIWebview so that i can assign the tableviewcell that particular height and disable its scrolling.

Comment: u just have to load web view. no scrollview,no tableview.

Comment: once i load the the webview then how will i check, whether a name,or an image is clicked and load it in different view.